# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_iterator2[typeof Symbol === "function"

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am implementing firebase with react native, here are the versions i am working with

```
"firebase": "^5.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react": "16.4.1",
```

But when i import firebase, it is showing following error :

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_iterator2[typeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator : "@@iterator"]()')
```

[image]

**Note :** Getting this error only on Android device, on iOS it is working perfect.

Comment: Did you add the firebase Android native SDK?

Comment: When you are using js version of firebase, native implementation is not needed, it is needed when you are using `react-native-firebase` library

Comment: But your context is react-native, u can't just use the JS one. react-native `fetch`, for example, has the same API but completely different implementation under the hood. You can't use the JS one, You must use the `react-native-firebase`.

Comment: I can, even it is working perfect with `react-native:0.55.4` and i have live projects also with firebase + react native. It is just the issue with version `0.56.0`

Comment: same issue, but I don't use firebase. any solution?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue when importing firebase and found the solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15902#issuecomment-373964965)

Add this in your index.js

```
// index.js
global.Symbol = require('core-js/es6/symbol');
require('core-js/fn/symbol/iterator');
require('core-js/fn/map');
require('core-js/fn/set');
require('core-js/fn/array/find');
```

The way I see it is that there are certain JS syntaxes that doesn't translate well for android to understand.

Comment: Does it mean that its issue from `firebase` and not from `react-native` team?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I'm a beginner so I'm not sure. But RN bridge sends json messages to android and I'm assuming firebase uses new syntax for its iterator where RN sends a message that android doesn't understand yet.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Actually I suggest installing an earlier version of firebase cause you will find more issues with the current version.

Comment: shot on the head. Excelente it works like a charm for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried solutions of above all but what solved my error was following these steps:

1. create a polyfills file code and put in a file named *polyfills.js*, at the same level with *index.js* (entry point of my react-native project)
2. the code:

```
global.Symbol = require('core-js/es6/symbol');
require('core-js/fn/symbol/iterator');
require('core-js/fn/map');
require('core-js/fn/set');
require('core-js/fn/array/find');
```

3. On the first line within *index.js* file include the following code:

```
import './polyfills.js';
```

Now Reload the app(Press R twice). Hope It works!

[Answer Reference](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/issues/1305#issuecomment-454645846)

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Syph, is not enough for me to run perfectly, I have to add following in "index.js" and it works for me.

```
global.Symbol = require('core-js/es6/symbol');
require('core-js/fn/symbol/iterator');
require('core-js/fn/map');
require('core-js/fn/set');
require('core-js/fn/array/find');

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    if (typeof Symbol === 'undefined') {
        if (Array.prototype['@@iterator'] === undefined) {
            Array.prototype['@@iterator'] = function () {
                let i = 0;
                return {
                    next: () => ({
                        done: i >= this.length,
                        value: this[i++],
                    }),
                };
             };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these JS syntaxes when importing firebase cannot be understood by Android. Adding these codes to your index.js might resolve it.

Note: If you are having separate index.android.js add these codes to that file.

```
global.Symbol = require('core-js/es6/symbol');
require('core-js/fn/symbol/iterator');
require('core-js/fn/map');
require('core-js/fn/set');
require('core-js/fn/array/find');
```